# Which type of data saving format will be effective?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have sliding drawer that have list of items such as checkbox,radio buttons,plain text,text box in first activity and expandable listview as well.
[image]

When i click on any of the items in sliding drawer the next activity opens to add the child and parent for the expandable list view.

[image]

and the items are added as

[image]

So now my problem is if again i click on any of the items in the drawer and again add the the child and parent the initial items in the expandable list disappears and newly added items appears in top. I mean as there. i want the added items simultaneously in the expandable list. I should be saved somewhere or what? I should not use the database here for future purpose. well in this case i need a guidance.what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation android offers a special feature called shared preference mainly it us used to store settings it stores everything in a xml file (you dont have to write explicitly on xml file android takes care of that )

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("file_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("KEY", "value");
        editor.putString("KEY", "value");
        editor.commit();//save changes to the file
```

Now to access the contents

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("file_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String x=sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "if_not_present_default_value");
String y=sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "if_not_present_default_value");
```

I hope what you are asking, this is the solution,using database for such small thing is not good approach.Hope it helps ,if I am wrong please correct me

Comment: yes i am also looking into it..an can i display it into expandable list..? i found   android startActivityForResult to pass them...can it be possible to display int the list rather than replacing the old ones?

Comment: Yes you can do that. When new items are added first save it after when new activity get created check the preference before drawing the new one